# Can you explain the what, how and why of the following "C" typedef struct code

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Here is some sample typedef struct

```
typedef struct _person {
   int age;
   float weight;
   int test;
} person;

int main()
{
    person *personPtr, person1;
    personPtr = &person1;   
    person *personPtr2, person2;
    personPtr2 = personPtr;   

    person1.test = 5;
    personPtr->age = 72;
    personPtr2->weight = 150;
```

All 3, person1  personPtr1 and personPtr2 all point to the same data
the lines I don't understand are:

```
    person *personPtr, person1;
    personPtr = &person1;
```

person is obviously the struct definition,  and *personPtr will create a pointer to the struct data
and I take it that  person1  is the actual data (memory space that is allotted)?

then why the next line,

```
    personPtr = &person1;
```

Didn't the preceding line already create personPtr as a pointer to person1 ?
I don't understand if and why are both lines of code needed ?

What I want to do is create a separate pointer to the person1 data.
I wasn't sure how to do it,  so I used

```
     person *personPtr2 person2
```

then i could equate the 2 pointers        personPtr2 = personPtr;
But, that is wasting memory since it is creating a second   person2 data i am not needing.

All i want to do is create a second ptr (handle) to the original struct data  (person1)
so how is that done?    By the way, this is interfacing to a library that has the typedef struct and all,   so i don't want to do it in the library,  but, in my external code.

Comment: *"Didn't the preceding line already create personPtr as a pointer to person1"* - at what point do you think such assignment happened on that line? I don't see any `=` there

Comment: Also this question seems to be not about `typedef struct` but about basic syntax for creating and assigning pointers? Nothing about it seems to be directly related to structs

Comment: `Type *pointer, variable;` declares (and, when at block scope) defines an uninitialized pointer to type `Type` named `pointer` and an uninitialized variable of type `Type` named `variable`. Both will uninitialized and unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
person *personPtr, person1;
```

is the same as

```
 person *personPtr;
 person person1;
```

ie a pointer to a person and an instance of a person

Answer (score 0):

> person is obviously the struct definition, and *personPtr will create
> a pointer to the struct data and I take it that person1 is the actual
> data (memory space that is allotted)?

Who did tell you that.

Comma separates definitions and both are unrelated to each other. Both are not initialized.

You need to initialize the pointer with the reference to struct.